# Selecting denominator for relative error margins

Tags: numerical-methods, average, floating-point

When looking at this page:  http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/

there are values `a`, and `b` that are being compared for being "nearly equal".  It is shown that absolute error margin will not work for small values of `a` and `b` and that relative error margin should be used.

Namely, the site uses $abs(a-b)/b$, and that makes the operation not commutative.  Why not use $abs(a-b)/a?$.

Is there a deeper meaning behind this?  For example, can I use the average, something like $abs(a-b)/(abs(a+b)/2)$ instead?

**Bonus**:  How do I interpret the result?  Namely, answers are different if I select $a$, $b$, or $a+b\over2$ or $max(a,b)$ for denominator.  Which one is right, or are they all "right", and this basically done for as long as we get a reasonably good relative error estimation in principle?

Answer (score 1):

I feel the same way:
in general, a problem
in which the parameters
are treated symmetrically
should have a result
that uses them symmetrically.

In this case,
I have used
$\dfrac{|a-b|}{\max(a, b, 1)}
$.
It's not differentiable,
but it does handle
the switch between
large and small
$a$ and $b$
nicely,
and it is
symmetric in them.